С++ 17 Разрешено константное вычисление
Изучаю С++ 17 раздел "Разрешено константное вычисление для всех аргументов шаблона, не являющихся типом".
Почему в VS2019 не компилируется код согласно изменению:
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <auto Value>
struct MyStruct
{
    void print()
    {
        cout << Value << endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    const char str[] = { "Hello, C++ 17!" };

    MyStruct<str> obj1;
    obj1.print();

    return 0;
}


Вынеси str на глобальный уровень и должно заработать
